# Android Foreground Services

Tags: android, foreground-service

I have a service which is called with

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    getActivity().startForegroundService(new Intent(getActivity(), 
Background.class));
} else {
    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), Background.class));
}
```

and the service it's self being

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Creating Notification",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //
    initChannels(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
            .setContentTitle("Zeep!?")
            .setTicker("Zeep!?")
            .setContentText("We're currently working in the background")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.zeep_icon_b)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1337, notification);
    //

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

but whenever I start the app and the close the app, it crashes and causes the phone to soft reboot, i'm so confused by it all, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My onStartCommand() looks like this:

```
     @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I take care of the notification stuff in onCreate() instead. Also, you need to call startForeground() immediately after calling startForegroundService():

```
     @Override
public void onCreate() {
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Create the channel for the notification
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        //Since MainActivity binds with the service and calls onCreate, we can actually call startForegroundService from within the service itself.
        startForegroundService(new Intent(ForegroundService.this, ForegroundService.class));
        //We only need to call this for SDK 26+, since startForeground always has to be called after startForegroundService.
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    }
    else {
        //Since MainActivity binds with the service and calls onCreate, we can actually call startService from within the service itself.
        startService(new Intent(ForegroundService.this, ForegroundService.class));
    }
```

Not saying this is the solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
START_NOT_STICKY
```

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, do not recreate the service unless there are pending intents to deliver. This is the safest option to avoid running your service when not necessary and when your application can simply restart any unfinished jobs.

```
START_STICKY
```

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand(), but do not redeliver the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand() with a null intent unless there are pending intents to start the service. In that case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable for media players (or similar services) that are not executing commands but are running indefinitely and waiting for a job.

```
START_REDELIVER_INTENT
```

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand() with the last intent that was delivered to the service. Any pending intents are delivered in turn. This is suitable for services that are actively performing a job that should be immediately resumed, such as downloading a file.

You can use `START_NOT_STICKY` but then you will have to manually handle the stopping of the service. 
Also remember that when you are calling a service from an activity the `onCreate()` doesn’t always gets called. Only when you are calling a service from a non activity it gets called else the `onStartCommand()` gets called.

I think this library has the best service implementation for android. Check it out [MockGeoFix](https://github.com/luv/mockgeofix/tree/master/app/src/main/java/github/luv/mockgeofix).